# Load image if found, else load another image

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

what I need to do is simple to say but (for me) hard to do:

using **javascript**, given an image name, ie "image01.jpg", I need to check if this image exists in a certain folder or path (local or on the web). If the image does not exist under that folder, I need to check if the same image exists in another folder.

for example, with pseudo code

```
imageToFind = 'image01.jpg'
path1 = 'users/john/images'
path2 = 'users/mike/img'

if path1+'/'+imageToFind exists
    //do something
else
    if path2+'/'+imageToFind exists
        //do something
    else
        print('NOT FOUND')
```

what kind of approach do you suggest? I tryed to achieve this using ajax first, and then using javascript's Image() , but I failed in both these cases.

Thanks in advance for any help, best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pretty much rely on native `onload` and `onerror` event handlers which fire for *Image nodes*. So it could look like

```
var images = ['users/john/images/image01.jpg','users/mike/img/image01.jpg','some/more/path/image01.jpg'];

(function _load( img ) {
    var loadImage = new Image();

    loadImage.onerror = function() {
        // image could not get loaded, try next one in list
        _load( images.shift() );
    };
    loadImage.onload = function() {
        // this image was loaded successfully, do something with it
    };

    loadImage.src = img;
}( images.shift() ));
```

This code probably does a little more than you actually asked for. You can basically but as much *image paths* as you wish into that array, the script will search the list until it could load one image successfully.

Comment: These may be a bit quirky in older IE versions (IE7 as I resemble).

Comment: @yunzen: older IE's might have a problem if you assign the *source* before you define the *onload* / *onerror* handlers.

Answer (score 6):

Use the onerror callback :

```
var img = new Image();
img.onerror = function(){
   img = new Image(); // clean the error (depends on the browser)
   img.onerror = function(){
       console.log('not found at all !');
   };
   img.src = path2+'/'+imageToFind;
};
img.src = path1+'/'+imageToFind;
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust your code so that if neither is found, it defaults to another image that is always going to exist? I tried replacing `console.log` with `img.src = <img that always exists>` but it did not work.

Comment: I think what happened is that it cached the page, so when I made the change it didn't do anything. Is there a way to suppress the error from when the first image doesn't load?

Comment: @Rhyono I edited. You're right about the need to clean, as there may be a problem on some browser.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
objImg = new Image();
objImg.src = 'photo.gif';

if(!objImg.complete)
 { 
      img.src = path2+'/'+imageToFind; //load other image
  }else{
     img.src = path1+'/'+imageToFind;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ask yourself: *why don't I know whether the images exist?*

I feel like you should not have this problem, or want to solve it in this way.