# If an image image path exists replace the text, if not display original image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I had set up a bit of code to replace images with their higher resolution versions. It looks like this

```
$("img[src*='.jpg']").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg','.highres.jpg'));
});
```

Which just looks for all image and replaces the file name.

Sometimes though, the high res image is not given the file name of 'highres.jpg'

What I would like to do, is if highres.jpg exists, display that one. otherwise just display the original.

Here is what I tried:

```
 $("img[src*='.jpg']").each(function(){
    var replaceImage = function() {
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg','.highres.jpg'));
     };
    if (replaceImage > -1) {
    replaceImage;
    };
});
```

Pretty sure I'm grasping at straws here and there's a better way to do this... cause it's not working :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Load image if found, else load another image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13126612/1492578)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I didn't find that it related closely enough with my example. It did however lead me to finding a solution, so thank you for that.

Comment: [Check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23638989/1492578). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct implementation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13126636/1492578) answer:

```
 $("img[src*='.jpg']").each(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');                       // The original src
    var highresSrc = imgSrc.replace('.jpg','.highres.jpg'); // High res src

    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function() {  // In case of error, revert to original
        img = new Image();
        img.src = imgSrc;
    };

    /*
    img.onload = function() {
        // Image has loaded successfully. Do something if you want.
        ...
    };
    */ 

    img.src = highresImg;       // Try loading highres
});
```